# Definition of Adic-filtration

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, group-rings

I am reading On the Associated Graded Ring of a Group Ring by DANIEL G. QUILLEN and this is the beginning of the article:

[image]

I have no idea what is $\overline{KG}$-adic filtration, as well as the definition of $\overline{KG}^n$ (or $\overline{KG^n}$?) there. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's the augmentation ideal filtration you where asking for yesterday.

Comment: Thanks @Hanno! Sorry that I have been asking too many questions on this topic. I am a beginner on this and am still confused with those definitions. By the way, if I would like to learn augmentation ideal filtration, is this Quillen's article a good place to start?

Comment: No need to apologize! However, I have to admit I don't know anything interesting to say about the augmentation ideal filtration in general. Maybe it's best to just keep reading and see what special properties of the $\overline{KG}$-adic and the general augmentation filtration you will need.